# After SSD upgrade, HP EliteBook Folio 9470m, boot hangs at start while in the HP ultra slim dock. Out of dock all works fine

Tags: ssd, dock

I've upgraded to an SSD drive. I've cloned the original, installed the new SSD internally, all works great. But when I put the system in the associated ultra thin docking station, the system hangs on the Windows startup screen. Out of the Dock works great. I have downgraded the OS to Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with my Ultrabook. It would hang during boot up when my external USB 3.0 HDD was connected. Do you happen to have any additional storage devices connected to the docking station? If so, try disconnecting them or changing the boot order settings to make sure the computer access the SDD before anything else when starting up.

If you determine that it is the docking station causing the problem, go into the Advanced System Settings -> Services and change the startup settings for anything associated with the docking station to "Delayed Startup" so that those services do not initiate until everything else has completely booted.